# Using Apache Buildr to build JRuby project?

Tags: jruby, buildr

The question came up [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424733/buildr-for-compiling-and-building-jruby-project), but wasn't actually answered then. How do you set up buildr to build JRuby projects?

Comment: buildr is oriented towards the compile-test-package-run model of project automation. AFAIK, JRuby projects (being more like Ruby projects than Java projects) don't usually follow this model.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: @RhettSutphin Eh, I basically want the dependency management part of buildr (I can write the rake tasks for building myself). I do have a thing against xml though, so I'd rather not touch maven myself if I can get around it somehow.

Comment: Is this pure Ruby or is there Java involved ? How are you using JRuby ? Are you spawning a container or using the JSR-223 approach ? Is your deliverable a .jar, a .war ?

Depending on those, the question may become quite different. If you use JRuby sparsely and just call it from a container, you'll want to place the Ruby in src/main/resources.